# CMake build error: Qt5PrintSupportConfig.cmake missing

Tags: c++, qt, build, cmake, mitk

I am trying to build build a C++ toolkit called MITK with CMake. But I am getting this Qt5 related error. I am using the open source version of Qt 5.7.1. I can't find any file with the name `Qt5PrintSupportConfig.cmake` inside the Qt5 folder. The closest thing I found was `windowsprintersupport.dll` inside the folder `printsupport`. What could be the probem?

```
CMake Error at C:/Qt5.7.1/5.7/winrt_x64_msvc2015/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:26 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5PrintSupport" with any of the following names:

    Qt5PrintSupportConfig.cmake
    qt5printsupport-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "Qt5PrintSupport" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
set "Qt5PrintSupport_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.

If "Qt5PrintSupport" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first): CMakeLists.txt:211 (find_package)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You downloaded the wrong Qt online installer.

The one which you installed is from here: https://www.qt.io/download/

The one which you want is here: https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/ for the latest version or here https://download.qt.io/archive/online_installers/2.0/ for older versions.

I am not sure what the difference is but the one you probably installed is the `normal` version while the one you need is the `unified` version, whatever that means. Once you installed it, check this directory: `C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\lib\cmake\Qt5PrintSupport` since now it should include the `Qt5PrintSupportConfig.cmake` file.